# Shell Script with environment variable

Tags: c, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a C program that has the following code at the end:

```
    memcpy(buff,"TEST=",4)
    putenv(buff)
    system("/bin/bash")
```

I put a new environment variable in a new shell. I want to then echo test into a text file which i can easily do. I then want to exit the shell and run it again so running this would look as follows

```
   ./cprog "some arg"
   echo $TEST > test.txt
   exit
   ./cprog "some arg"
   echo $TEST > test.txt
   exit
```

I have to keep exiting so I can change the TEST variable. How could I make this work in a shell script so i could just keep looping and running the c program so I could change the argument but never exiting the shell script itself.

Comment: What is the first `memcpy` supposed to do ? As it stands it copies the 4 characters `TEST` into `buff`.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Why are you starting an extra shell from inside the program?  You talk about changing the TEST variable, but don't say how you change it.  Your memcpy has the wrong length, and you never assign a value to TEST.

Comment: buff already has stuff in it and i'm adding that to the front should be 5 sorry

Comment: A program can't change the environment of the controlling shell.

Comment: if i don't start an extra shell that variable is empty when i echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are not an appropriate way of passing information from a process to the user or an invoking process. You should be writing this information to stdout (with any other info to stderr) and redirecting it appropriately.

If you insist on this solution, though, you can use

```
for p in "one arg" "another arg" "more"
do 
    echo 'printf "%s\n" "$TEST" >> test.txt' | ./cprog "$p"
done
```

This will input the command to write the variable to the file to your program, and then exit the shell (because input ends).

At the end, you'll have all the values of `$TEST` concatenated in the file `test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible for your program to change the environment of the parent process, which is what you seem to be trying to do.

What you can do instead, however, is to have your program simply print the desired output, and call it using `eval`.

> ```
> $ ./cprog "wibble"
> TEST=wibble
> $ eval `./cprog "wibble"`
> $ echo ""TEST\" is now equal to \"$TEST\""
> "TEST" is now equal to "wibble"
> $
> ```

Comment: Obviously, this assumes that you trust the output of `cprog` (e.g. it's not affected by user input), since otherwise someone could manipulate it into writing `TEST=foo rm -rf /` which eval would happily execute.

Comment: The whole question is predicated on trusting `cprog`, so I don't see the problem. Note that `cprog` is questioner's own program, from the question.

Comment: You have to trust that `cprog` appropriately escapes any values it reads from any data it processes for the shell that you're currently running. This security issue is introduced with the change you're suggesting, and wasn't there before.